# Unexpected token 'not' only happens when in same line

Tags: python, visual-studio

So this is a question about the ambiguity introduced with questioning indent, not really the matter of `not`.

==============Original Question==============

I'm using Visual Studio. Basically here's the simplified example of what I've encountered:

```
class sample():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xData = [0]
        self.yData = [0]
    def trySomething(self, x = [], y = []):
        if not x: x = self.xData; if not y: y = self.yData
        #BlaBlaBla
```

Here I want to check if x and y has an input, if not, using the variables of the class itself. However, that can't run, the  `if not y:` is underscored with red waving line saying `Unexpected token 'not'`, like this:
[image: demo]
The wired thing is that once I split it into another row, things would be fixed:

```
class sample():
    def __init__(self):
        self.xData = [0]
        self.yData = [0]
    def trySomething(self, x = [], y = []):
        if not x: x = self.xData; 
        if not y: y = self.yData
        #BlaBlaBla
```

So what's wrong writing them together in one row? Or is that some sort of bug of Visual Studio?

Comment: why do you add a `;`  ?

Comment: @scharette, because without a semicolon, you can't have two statements on one line.

Comment: @Kevin Oh he needs both on the same line. My bad, I really hate looking code in an image, I always put my attention to posted code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ambiguity. Which one do you mean?

```
    if not x: 
        x = self.xData
    if not y: 
        y = self.yData
```

or

```
    if not x: 
        x = self.xData
        if not y: 
            y = self.yData
```

Here's more details: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

TLDR Just don't use `;` in this case

Answer (score 2):

This is logical. If you **write a lexical scope** (like `if`), even **after the semicolon**, it is **still under the `if`**.

For example:

```
>>> if False: print('a'); print('b')
... 
>>>
```

(prints nothing)

So:

```
if False: print('a'); print('b')
```

is **equivalent to**:

```
if False:
    print('a')
    print('b')  # also under the if
```

Since introducing a new scope makes it terribly hard to understand, the syntax is not allowed in Python. It would create ambugity.

So the statement you wrote was incorrect: you would have scoped the `if not y` under the `if not x`, which was not what you meant.

Comment: i don't think there is a better explanation than that. excellent :)